# Can Firebase Database rules access data in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using both types of databases, Firebase Database and Firestore in the same project, for different data. Is it possible to write a Firebase Database rule that accesses data from my Firestore database? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  Security rules currently cannot work between products.  The best you can do is mirror your data between products.